# Combining files column-wise by first column as key (using grep or awk, etc.)

Tags: awk, columns

Here are my two files

## 1.txt

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

## 2.txt

```
2       a
5       3
```

than i get the file by `awk -F '\t' 'NR==FNR{F1[$0];next}$1 in F1{print}' 1.txt 2.txt`

```
2       a
5       3
```

but i want to get file like this

```
1
2    a
3
4
5    3
```

or

```
1     0
2     a
3     0
4     0
5     3
```

Comment: Please select the blocks of code and data, and use the `{}` button to mark them up as code. Then you can remove any incorrect blank lines

Comment: Please also explain what you want to the code to do.

Comment: If I run your code with what I think you mean by those files I get nothing output. It's _really important_ that what you show us is (a) well formatted so we can understand it, (b) accurate such that when your code is applied to the examples you give us, it produces the output you say it does

Comment: @roaima you likely get no output because the limitations of the site's formatting have converted tabs in `2.txt` to spaces

Comment: @steeldriver sure. But if it had been formatted properly I'd have probably noticed the attempt at tab separated fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having converted spaces in `2.txt` back to tabs with `sed -i 's/  */\t/' 2.txt`,

```
awk -F '\t' '
  BEGIN{OFS=FS} NR==FNR{F1[$1]=$2; next} {print $1, ($1 in F1)? F1[$1] : 0}
' 2.txt 1.txt
1       0
2       a
3       0
4       0
5       3
```

Comment: Regarding `Having converted spaces in 2.txt back to tabs with sed -i 's/  */\t/' 2.txt` - there's no need to do that, just don't set `FS` to a tab, i.e. use `awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}` or similar instead of `awk -F '\t' ' BEGIN{OFS=FS}`

Answer (score 2):

Using `join` instead of `awk`, which assumes that the two files are sorted on the first field (which they are in the question):

```bash
$ join -a 1 1.txt 2.txt
1
2 a
3
4
5 3
```

The `-a 1` option makes the utility report all lines from the first file, not just the ones that join on the first field.

To additionally replace the missing values with zeros, we have to ask `join` for the specific fields to output, and to also replace the missing ones with `0`.  With `-o 1.1,2.2` we ask for the first field from the first file and the second field from the second file, and with `-e 0` we make it replace missing data with `0`:

```bash
$ join -a 1 -o 1.1,2.2 -e 0 1.txt 2.txt
1 0
2 a
3 0
4 0
5 3
```

Use `-t $'\t'` with `join` to explicitly set the delimiter to a tab character.  This would also cause the utility to use tabs in the output.